# Using Nlog to write structured logs to Google Stackdriver

Tags: nlog, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using the [Google.Cloud.Logging.NLog](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Logging.NLog/Google.Cloud.Logging.NLog) target to write logs to Stackdriver.
I'd like to use Nlog & Stackdriver structured logging capabilities by sending a JSON payload as per the [Stackdriver documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging):

[image]

Logs are coming through but I don't seem to be populating the **jsonPayload** property in the logs, which will mean that I'm not sending a JSON payload. Do I need to [configure  a JsonLayout](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout#from-the-api) for every type of log message stated below?

### Target code

```
GoogleStackdriverTarget googleTarget = new GoogleStackdriverTarget
{
    ProjectId = "123456",
    Name = "desktop app",
    CredentialFile = Path.Combine(@"my path to the json file"),
    ContextProperties = { new TargetPropertyWithContext{Name = "MyCustomContextProperty", 
    Organization.Id}},
    IncludeEventProperties = true,
    Layout = new JsonLayout()
};
```

### Logs

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Logon by {user} from {ip_address}", "Kenny", "127.0.0.1");

LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("{shopitem} added to basket by {user}", new { Id = 6, Name = "Jacket", Color = "Orange" }, "Kenny");
```

### Result in Stackdriver

[image: result]

Comment: Think you are waiting for this PR: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/pull/2256 (Maybe you can comment on wanting named properties also as labels)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm waiting for, thanks. Feel free to submit as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the following PR, that adds support for sending Google JsonPayload:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/pull/2256

**Update** That now have evolved into an official nuget-package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Logging.NLog

Comment: Just downloaded the beta NuGet package and we now have a JsonPayload. Thanks again for this.